# background image / sprite positioning covered by unknown

Tags: css, background-image, sprite

In: http://jsfiddle.net/elasticGurl/CpBX5/

I'm having a problem with my CSS and the background image hiding part of the left edge of the image (where the drop shadow is). See the bottom image (included only for reference) with the red arrows to see where the problem is. It's on the left, roughly from the top of "Devices" to the bottom of "Access." This is so simple, yet I don't can't see it.

http://jsfiddle.net/elasticGurl/CpBX5/

The problem CSS is the following:

```
form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner { list-style: none outside none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner li { background: url('http://www.myproduction-1.info/_BG/_images/sbsignup_pricing_generic.png') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; font-size: 14px; background-position: -5px -133px; width: 534px; height: 62px; margin-left:274px; }

form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner li.access { background-position: -5px -133px; width: 502px; height: 11px;}
form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner li span { display: block; float: left; text-align: center; }
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background-position` from negative to zero. Then adjust for the margins.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rCJaN/

```css
form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner li { background: url('http://www.myproduction-1.info/_BG/_images/sbsignup_pricing_generic.png') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; font-size: 14px; background-position: 0px -133px; width: 534px; height: 62px; margin-left:269px; }
form#frm_select_a_plan ul#select_a_plan_inner li.access { background-position: 0px -133px; height: 11px;}
form#frm_select_a_plan #select_a_plan_bottom { margin: 0px; background: url('http://www.myproduction-1.info/_BG/_images/sbsignup_pricing_generic.png') no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;  list-style: none outside none; background-position: 0px -307px; width: 534px;height: 123px; margin-left:269px; }
```

Comment: Antony, I have another similar question if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762075/ie7-issue-with-div-that-is-partially-hidden-covered-by-image